# jhipster deployed to heroku lose custom css's

Tags: jhipster

In my jhipster application I have a custom css (.css other than "main"), once I deployed to heroku, my custom css seems not be found. The main.css in the index.html is called as: styles/74de7bc1.main.css but my custom css is called as: styles/custom.css and and is not found. I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSS has been renamed, it is because you have packaged your application with the "production" profile. Please note it is in src/main/webapp/dist directory, and this is not your original index.html.
The current Heroku sub-generator works with the "default" profile, which is the "development" profile. You can try to run with the "production" profile on Heroku (see the documentation, you need to set this up in an environment variable), but this is not tested or supported.
This shouldn't be hard to do, but as we are currently in BETA mode. I'm first trying to have the Heroku sub generator working fine with the default options, before working on more advanced usage.